# .Net (C#) - SSRS .rdl file not getting written correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, ssrs-2012

I have a problem with using XML (to read/write a SSRS report definition in rdl format). I'm trying to read it and then write it again. (I intend to do some editing as well, but that has been disabled for now)
When writing it again, I lose a lot of formatting and also seem to be losing data. The file size for the written file is ~30-40% of the file I read in, even though I have disabled the editing bits for now.
I've written a reader:

```
public class XMLLoader
{
    public SSRSDocument Load(string path, string filename)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path+filename);
        var result = new SSRSDocument
        {
            Report = doc,
            Path = path,
            Filename = filename
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

and a writer:

```
public class XMLWriter
{

    public void Write(SSRSDocument document, string path, string filename)
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + filename);
        document.Report.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

The SSRS document is a struct with the XML and some metadata (for now just the XML and the location of the file, but this will expand later on):

```
public struct SSRSDocument
{
    public XmlDocument Report { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

}
```

My input file is 450 KiB, but my output is only 170KiB?

Also a lot of the line endings have dropped off, but it seems some of the report definition data has also vanished. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here. Shouldn't I be getting the same file in my output from what I've read with my reader, when I'm not changing anything between reading and writing?

[edit]Unfortunately I can't post the RDL's due to the sensitive nature of the data in there.

Comment: You could just be loosing white spaces.  Make sure you are reading and writing the correct files.

Comment: Damn, it turns out you're right. I googled a bit on the preservation of formatting and the report now comes out the same way as the source file. Thnx :)